# Python Django and React: CSRF Authtification failing, HTTP 403

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, csrf, vite

I have the following Django-Setup to ensure CORS between my React Frontend and my Django Backend:

views.py:

```
import json

from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponseBadRequest
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

from .models import FavouriteLocation
from .utils import get_and_save_forecast


def get_forecast(request, latitude, longitude):
    forecast = get_and_save_forecast(latitude, longitude)
    data = {
        'latitude': str(forecast.latitude),
        'longitude': str(forecast.longitude),
        'generation_time_ms': str(forecast.generation_time_ms),
        'utc_offset_seconds': forecast.utc_offset_seconds,
        'timezone': forecast.timezone,
        'timezone_abbreviation': forecast.timezone_abbreviation,
        'elevation': str(forecast.elevation),
        'temperature': str(forecast.temperature),
        'windspeed': str(forecast.windspeed),
        'winddirection': str(forecast.winddirection),
        'weathercode': forecast.weathercode,
        'is_day': forecast.is_day,
        'time': forecast.time.isoformat(),  # convert datetime to string
        'hourly_time': forecast.hourly_time,
        'temperature_2m': forecast.temperature_2m,
        'relativehumidity_2m': forecast.relativehumidity_2m,
        'windspeed_10m': forecast.windspeed_10m,
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)


def get_favourites(request):
    favourites = FavouriteLocation.objects.all()
    data = [{'id': fav.id, 'name': fav.name, 'latitude': fav.latitude, 'longitude': fav.longitude} for fav in
            favourites]
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)


@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def add_favourite(request):
    try:
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        name = data['name']
        latitude = data['latitude']
        longitude = data['longitude']
        FavouriteLocation.objects.create(name=name, latitude=latitude, longitude=longitude)
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'})
    except (KeyError, ValueError):
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()


@require_http_methods(["DELETE"])
def delete_favourite(request, favourite_id):
    try:
        fav = FavouriteLocation.objects.get(id=favourite_id)
        fav.delete()
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'})
    except FavouriteLocation.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()


def csrf(request):
    token = get_token(request)
    return JsonResponse({'csrfToken': token})
```

settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'secret'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'betterWeather.apps.BetterweatherConfig',
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:5173",
]
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ['http://localhost:5173']
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:5173']
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES = [
    'http://localhost:3030',
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'weatherApp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'weatherApp.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, register_converter
from betterWeather import views, converters
from betterWeather.views import csrf

register_converter(converters.DecimalConverter, 'decimal')

urlpatterns = \[
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('api/weather/\<decimal:latitude\>/\<decimal:longitude\>/', views.get_forecast, name='get_forecast'),
path('api/favourites/', views.get_favourites, name='get_favourites'),
path('api/favourites/add/', views.add_favourite, name='add_favourite'),
path('api/favourites/delete/\<int:favourite_id\>/', views.delete_favourite, name='delete_favourite'),
path('api/csrf/', csrf, name='csrf'),
\]
```

To get the CSRF-Token out of the Cookies and use it in the following Request-Headers in following POST-Requests, I have the following React Code:

App.jsx:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import {useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Forecast from './components/Forecast';
import Favorites from './components/Favorites';
import AddFavorite from './components/AddFavorite';
import LastForecasts from './components/LastForecasts';
import Footer from './components/Footer';

const App = () =\> {

    useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/csrf/', { withCredentials: true })
        .then((response) => {
            const csrftoken = response.data.csrfToken; // make sure the key is correct
            axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
                // Do something before request is sent
                config.headers['X-CSRFToken'] = csrftoken;
                return config;
            }, function (error) {
                // Do something with request error
                return Promise.reject(error);
            });
    
            axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
            console.log('CSRF token set successfully');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error getting CSRF token', error);
        });

}, \[\]);

    return (
        <Router>
            <Navbar/>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/forecast" element={<Forecast/>}/>
                <Route path="/favorites" element={<Favorites/>}/>
                <Route path="/add-favorite" element={<AddFavorite/>}/>
                <Route path="/last-forecasts" element={<LastForecasts/>}/>
            </Routes>
            <Footer/>
        </Router>
    )

};

export default App;
```

AddFavorite.jsx:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';
import {useCookies} from 'react-cookie';

const AddFavorite = () =\> {
const location = useLocation();
const \[name, setName\] = useState('');
const \[latitude, setLatitude\] = useState('');
const \[longitude, setLongitude\] = useState('');
const \[cookies\] = useCookies(\['csrftoken'\]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (location.state) {
            setLatitude(location.state.latitude);
            setLongitude(location.state.longitude);
        }
    }, [location.state]);
    
    const isValidLongitude = (num) => {
        return !isNaN(num) && num > -90 && num < 90;
    };
    
    const isValidLatitude = (num) => {
        return !isNaN(num) && num > -180 && num < 180;
    };
    
    const addFavorite = async () => {
        if (latitude === '' || !isValidLatitude(latitude)) {
            alert('Invalid longitude, must be between -180 and 180.');
            return;
        }
        if (longitude === '' || !isValidLongitude(longitude)) {
            alert('Invalid latitude, must be between -90 and 90.');
            return;
        }
    
        await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/favourites/add/', {
            name,
            latitude,
            longitude,
        }, {
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': cookies.csrftoken
            }
        }).then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    
        setName('');
        setLatitude('');
        setLongitude('');
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(cookies);
    }, [cookies]);
    
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center pt-8 bg-gray-100 min-h-screen">
            <div className="bg-white px-8 py-6 shadow-lg rounded-lg w-full md:w-3/5 lg:w-1/3">
                <div className="flex flex-col items-center space-y-4">
                    <input
                        id="name"
                        name="name"
                        value={name}
                        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                        className="border-2 border-gray-200 p-3 rounded-lg w-full focus:border-blue-500"
                        placeholder="Name"
                        autoComplete="off"
                    />
                    <input
                        id="forecastLatitude"
                        name="forecastLatitude"
                        value={latitude}
                        onChange={(e) => setLatitude(e.target.value)}
                        className="border-2 border-gray-200 p-3 rounded-lg w-full focus:border-blue-500"
                        placeholder="Longitude"
                        autoComplete="off"
                    />
                    <input
                        id="forecastLongitude"
                        name="forecastLongitude"
                        value={longitude}
                        onChange={(e) => setLongitude(e.target.value)}
                        className="border-2 border-gray-200 p-3 rounded-lg w-full focus:border-blue-500"
                        placeholder="Latitude"
                        autoComplete="off"
                    />
                    <button
                        onClick={addFavorite}
                        className="bg-blue-500 text-white px-6 py-2 rounded-lg m-1 hover:bg-blue-600"
                    >
                        Add to favorites
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );

};

export default AddFavorite;
```

I was expecting it to work.
The cookie, so also the token are being GET-requested by the frontend.
There is also a CSRF-Token in the request headers, of the following POST-Requests.

The problem is, it still doesn't work.

I am not quite experienced since this is my first Django Web-App with a seperate Frontend, so I am hoping to find someone with a solution.

Greetings
OG